# 9.1 Deployer extension via Add-on

Tags: content-delivery, sites-9.1, add-on

Just checking the 9.1 docs for implementing [deployer extension via Add-on](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/725400/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/content-deployer-extension):

> Unlike other Extensions, the Content Deployer does not allow for
> multiple Extensions to be added to it at the same time. Rather, when
> you installed Content Deployer, you added an Add-on containing one
> single Extension, possibly containing resources for multiple Content
> Deployer enhancements (say, both for Experience Optimization and for
> Context Expressions), and to add your custom Content Deployer
> enhancement, you'd need to add resources and Pipeline elements to the
> existing Extension.

So if you've already deployed an Deployer extension via Add-on, say the Context Expression Extension - Deployer DX Extension, you'd have to modify this SDL add-on to include your own custom extension and then deploy just this combined extension?

You can't deploy your own custom deployer extension as its own Add-on?